# Django FilePathField raises file not found error

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I've defined a Django model which makes use of `FilePathField(allow_files=False, allow_folders=True)` which shall allow to define a required (not optional) file system directory in the model. If I try to add a new model in the admin interface I get a file not found error. All my other models registered the same way are just working fine. If I'd use `CharField()` instead of `FilePathField()` to hold the file system directory path I'd simply define a default value like `CharField(default='')`.

How can I fix the model making use of the `FilePathField` field?

Comment: Are you using relative path or absolute path?

Comment: I'd be interested in both variants.

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered same problem and the cause of the error is that django tries to scan the directory in order to get list of files that will be displayed as choices in html widget.
There are few solutions.

- If you don't mind limiting what paths can be added by users just add `path=/some/dir` to `FilePathField`
- If you don't want to limit paths but don't care about ability to update path trough admin just set `editable=False` in `FilePathField`
- If you want both  you can replace widget in admin for this particular field to classic text input.